# Expression engine: This form has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: expressionengine

I've got a problem with the contact form in Expression Engine. I'm using the code from the docs but after submitting I'm getting this error :

```
This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.
```

My code:

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="my@emailadress.com" charset="utf-8"}
    <h2>Support Form</h2>
    <p>
            <label for="from">Your Email:</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="40" maxlength="35" value="{member_email}" />
    </p>
    <p>
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="Contact Form" />
    </p>
    <p>
            <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40">
                    Support Email from: {member_name}
                    Sent at:  {current_time format="%Y %m %d"}
            </textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
            <input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit Form' />
    </p>
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

I'm using Expression Engine 2.8.0. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 9):

EE requires an XID to be in the form. There is a global variable you can use to generate an XID hash:

<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />

http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/putting-the-secure-in-secure-mode-forms

Comment: Wouldn't exp:email:contact_form include this hash "automatically"?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 3):

For us, adding this to the config.php 'fixed' the problem (more like, put a bandaid on it since it's not an ideal situation)

```
$config[‘disable_csrf_protection’] = “y”;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem only in Chrome and not in Firefox or Safari. I dug into the PHP and realized that it failed this check in Csrf.php:

```
// Fetch data, these methods enforce token time limits
    $this->fetch_session_token();
    $this->fetch_request_token();
// Main check
    if ($this->request_token === $this->session_token)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Then I realized that I had set Chrome to block cookies. I set it so Chrome would allow cookies and I am no longer getting that error message.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's a problem with the secure forms XID hash. You can only submit a form once while using "secure forms" (to stop spammers hijacking them).

A quick way of disabling it is to open **system/expressionengine/config/config.php** and add this down the bottom to disable it. See if that makes a difference for you.

```
$config["secure_forms"] = "n";
```

Obviously using secure forms is preferable though.

Comment: Found this answer also somewhere on the internet, tried it but didn't help, thanks for helping!

Comment: This is a very bad idea, secure forms are here for a purpose.